# When implementing Trees/Heaps/Lists etc, why should a `find` method return an iterator to the object instead of the obect itself?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I see a lot of different C++ programmers more knowledgeable than myself do this all the time in their data structure implementations. For example in [this AVL tree implementation](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=avl-tree),

```
/**
* iterator find(const Key& key);
* const_iterator find(const Key& key);
* Usage: if (myAVLTree.find("Skiplist") != myAVLTree.end()) { ... }
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Returns an iterator to the entry in the AVL tree with the specified key,
* or end() as as sentinel if it does not exist.
*/
iterator find(const Key& key);
const_iterator find(const Key& key) const;
```

I'm trying to figure out in what situation this would be more useful than just returning the value that corresponds to key.

If I were to adopt this into my own implementations (assuming I was designing some sort of container) when would it benefit me to do so?

Comment: What if you can't find the key ?

Comment: Why not just return a constant value such as an integer that indicates the value wasn't found?

Comment: If your value's type is int, how can you tell the difference between that "not-found" value and the value associated with the key you wanted to find ?

Comment: iterators have value outside of dereferencing the actual pointer.  for example, you can move forward or backward in the collection.

Comment: ah @Chnossos I see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning an iterator has several significant advantages:

(1) It's a good strategy for indicating failure if the key is not found; namely, returning `end()` clearly indicates the key was not found.  The alternatives include throwing an exception, (which the `at()` member function will do), or returning `nullptr`, which would require that a pointer is *also* returned on success.

(2) Certain data structures maintain an *order*, such as `std::map`.  When an iterator is returned, this enables the caller to increment or decrement the iterator to get the next/previous key/value pair in the ordering.

(3) Many standard container member functions take an iterator as a parameter, such as `std::vector::erase` or `std::map::erase`.  By passing in an iterator, the container may be able to efficiently operate on specific elements, without having to do another lookup by key.  For example, `std::map::erase(const key_type&)` is necessarily an O(log(N)) operation, but `std::map::erase(iterator)` is an O(1) operation.

Comment: One more advantage: returning an iterator does not involve copying the value found.

Answer (score 1):

If the value will not be found what are you going to return?! Any value that you are going to return can be a potential value of the container. In this case how to distinguish whether the value was not found or the returned value is an actual value of the container?

Answer (score 1):

An iterator allows you to manipulate the object found *as part of the container*, i.e., delete it, replace it by something else, ...